# GSAP timeline with repeat is breaking the draggable ease flow

Tags: javascript, draggable, gsap

I see that using the "repeat:-1" in timeline is breaking the draggable behavior ease flow.
https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/WNedayo?editors=1111

If use "**repeat:-1**" to loop the animation in above code pen code. observe that drag ease is breaking.

```
.to("#Handle", {
  duration: 100,
  x: 1000,
  repeat:-1,
  ease: "none"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put repeat in [right place](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline/repeat()):

```js
handle.t1 = gsap.timeline({
  repeat: -1,
  onStart() {
    console.log('start');
  },
  onComplete() {
    console.log('complete');
  }
})
.to("#Handle", {
  duration: 100,
  x: 1000,
  ease: "none"
});
```